# tar very large files to FTP directly splited into smaller files

Tags: linux, ftp, backup, tar, large-data

I need to backup a large server into FTP storage. I can tar all files, I can upload using FTP and I can split the tar file into many small files.

But the problem is I can't do these three steps in one step. I can tar to FTP directly, I can tar with split, but can't tar with FTP and split.

The OS is CentOS 6.2
The Files Size more than 800G

Thanks

Comment: Why does this have to be done in a single step? Is there a reason you can't write a shell script to do all three steps?  If disk space is an issue, what about using `rsync` instead of tar-ing and FTP-ing?

Comment: number of steps is not an issue, I can't save the compressed file in the same server. I need to make a scheduled backup to compress the full system (each week) and save it in FTP server, and incremental backup each day. So sure I need a script, but how? :D

Comment: Can you SSH into the remote server? Here are [directions for using `tar` with a remote server over an SSH tunnel](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/).

Comment: No, it is ftp or sftp only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To can tar, split and ftp a directory with one command line you need the following:

split command write to the standard output only, so you can't pass the file to another command like ftp to process it, to do so you need to patch split to can use the --filter option to can pass the output file to ftp "on the fly" without having to save to hard disk by setting up the $FILE environmental variable with the output file (the file names would be x00, x01, x02 ...).

1) Here is the split patch: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2011-01/txt3j8asgk8WH.txt
After patching split command, you would see in the man that the --filter option available in your split command.

2) install the ncftp ftp client which is a good ftp client that allows you to connect to ftp and put file in one line command, without waiting for the ftp response like ordinary ftp client. the ncftp is useful to integrate with scripts and so on.

here is the command that would compress /home directory with tar split it to 100MB small files and transfer each file through FTP

```
tar cvz -i /home | split -d -b 100m  --filter 'ncftpput -r 10 -F -c -u ftpUsername -p ftpPassword ftpHost $FILE'
```

note that we used the ncftpput that would pass the $FILE to ftp in single command too.
additional ftp options: 
-r 10: allows you to try to reconnect 10 times after loosing connection with ftp.
-F: To use passive mode.
-c: takes the input from stdin.

To merge the split files (x00, x01, x02, x03 ...) to can extract the file use following command

```
cat x* > originalFile.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a shell script and use

```
tar zcf - /usr/folder | split -b 30720m - /usr/archive.tgz
```

and then upload to FTP also because once you are doing `tar` and putting onto FTP then how can you split.

Comment: I can't save the compressed file in the same server, no available space.

Comment: So that means you are running out of space so you have to make sure you have enough space to keep the compressed files or attach a free drive or partition to save the files

Comment: sorry, but there is no larger space, we have about 1TB files :D it is not easy task :D